# why showing Access Denied while intergrating google calendar with springboot app. and try to create events

Tags: java, spring-boot, events, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

Why i am getting this error in google calendar integration. i give all permissions and scope from my app.

why showing Access Denied while intergrating google calendar with springboot app. and try to create events.

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:358) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

This is my config file -

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.WebSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                
                
            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
}

}
```

Can some one tell me what is problem with my code. i wanted to create event manually